# pandas groupBy ignoring date grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

quick question about pandas groupby.

Rows are in the following format

| id | date | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 60630b503ff132001be0ba85 | 2021-03-30T11:28:16.153Z | int | int | int |

I'm converting the timestamp to a date:

```py
df['date'] = df['date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Then trying to groupby on id and the **day** of the date. These are essentially "sign-in" timestamps so the same `id` can have multiple rows (per day), then summing all of the additional columns (ints)

```py
gdf = df.groupby([df['date'].dt.day, 'id'], as_index=False).sum()
```

This seems to be working, but the date column is being dropped despite the `as_index` flag set to `false` while the `id` isn't. Is there any way around this such that both columns are displayed per row?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: why don't you create a new column with the `df['date'].dt.day` and then do the groupby on that column?

Comment: @IanWright Well, I feel dumb. That worked. Thank you.